# Can I wildcard disavow all links from any site on a specific top level domain?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, negative-seo, disavow-links

So lately I found more than 7,500 links our website that are coming from spam sites. I used disavow to get rid of them.

In the future though, nobody stops a spammer to make

- `abc.tk`
- `foo.tk`
- `bar.tk`
- `LOL.tk`
- etc etc

and use all of them against our web page again.
Is there a way to disavow anything ending with `.tk`once and for all?
Something that will look like the `*` on a file search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I wildcard disavow all links from any site on a specific top level domain?

There is not currently any wildcard capability, no.

If that ever changes (which is unlikely -- too dangerous), it would be mentioned [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2648487).

Unfortunately, link disavowal is a very manual process, but at the same time that helps prevent users from going overboard and mistakenly destroying their rankings.

Comment: I don't find it dangerous to wildcard specific domains, especially if they do more harm than good. Free domains that spammers mostly use, can be prevented. As long as it is a manual job, I am on to make a csv to google report text automation to handle stuff faster. Thank you for your reply.